# i am trying to delete a column with the name "1" on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to delete a column with the name "1"   on pandas
but i am getting a keyerror

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1967, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/tamil/RnD/PreProcessing-1.0.1/app/app.py", line 86, in <lambda>
    del_column_button = tk.Button(preprocessing_frame,text="Delete The Column",command=lambda:open_delete_column_window())
                                                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/tamil/RnD/PreProcessing-1.0.1/app/app.py", line 113, in open_delete_column_window
    df = df.drop(column_name,axis = 1)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/tamil/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5568, in drop
    return super().drop(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/tamil/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4782, in drop
    obj = obj._drop_axis(labels, axis, level=level, errors=errors)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/tamil/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4824, in _drop_axis
    new_axis = axis.drop(labels, errors=errors)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/tamil/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 7069, in drop
    raise KeyError(f"{labels[mask].tolist()} not found in axis")
KeyError: "['1'] not found in axis"
```

here is the dataframe

```
     Index                       Test               Result                               Method  Method_new    0    1    2    3
0       0                  WBC COUNT          (H) 70.0 fL                            Impedance           3  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
1       1                  RBC COUNT   (H) 31.3 x 10^6/µL                            Impedance           3  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
2       2                        MCH          (H) 21.9 pg                           Calculated           1  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
3       3                       MCHC        (H) 30.1 g/dL                           Calculated           1  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
4       4                        MCV          (H) 72.3 fL                            Impedance           3  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
5       5             PLATELET COUNT  (H) 167.0 x 10^3/µL                            Impedance           3  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
6       6                        RDW           (H) 11.8 %                           Calculated           1  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
7       7                        MPV         (H) 0.136 fL                            Impedance           3  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
8       8                        PCT            (H) 0.9 %                           Calculated           1  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
9       9                  TOTAL WBC    (H) 8.2 x 10^3/µL  Automated (Sysmex/light microscopy)           0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
10     10                 NEUTROPHIL           (H) 65.9 %                   Differential count           2  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
11     11                 LYMPHOCYTE           (H) 18.4 %                   Differential count           2  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
12     12                 EOSINOPHIL            (H) 9.0 %                   Differential count           2  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
13     13                   MONOCYTE            (H) 6.5 %                   Differential count           2  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
14     14                   BASOPHIL            (H) 0.0 %                   Differential count           2  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
15     15  ABSOLUTE NEUTROPHIL COUNT   (H) 53.8 x 10^3/µL                           Calculated           1  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
16     16  ABSOLUTE EOSINOPHIL COUNT    (H) 1.0 x 10^3/µL                           Calculated           1  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
17     17  ABSOLUTE LYMPHOCYTE COUNT   (H) 12.9 x 10^3/µL                           Calculated           1  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
```

but when i tried to do a

```
df  = df.drop(column_name,axis = 1)
```

->where column_name is "1"

i am getting the above error

**Found a Solution :**

I converted all the column names into a list and converted all the elements of the list into string and got the index for '1' and used it to drop the column

```
column_name = '1'
list_string = df.columns.tolist()
list_column_names = [str(x) for x in list_string]
column_index  = list_column_names.index(column_name)
df = df.drop(df.columns[column_index], axis=1)
```

I think there is problem when reading the values as drop() might treat 1 and '1' different ,not sure tho

if anyone and find a better solution please let me know :)

by the way I am using pandas and python 3.11

Comment: hi please post your code as well as your dataframe

Comment: `del df["1"]` ?

Comment: you can delete a column with the following syntax: df.drop('column_name', axis=1, inplace=True)

Comment: is your column really called '1' or is it the column with the index so to speak one?

Comment: so as we see your df, which one you want to delete?

Comment: check near Method_new there are a set of columns named 0,1,2,3  : ( i did a OneHotEncoding at the Method column )

Answer (score 1):

The error states there KeyError: "['1'] not found in axis", meaning that you don't refer to the right column or '1' doesn't even exist in the dataframe.

To see columns in your dataframe, you can check with

```
df.columns
```

or

```
print(df.columns)
```

To delete (or drop i might say) column you can do like following

```
df.drop(['column_name1', 'column_name2'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

- your to be dropped column 'column_name' stored in the list which you can drop more than 1 column
- axis=1 means that you want to drop column axis (axis=0 dropping the
  row axis by index), and
- inplace=True means that the changes is
  automatically applied to the dataframe without assigning it to
  variable.